# declaration of non-variable in loop initial decleration

Tags: loops, variables, declaration

I'm compiling a code that I compiled before successfully. But this time its giving me an error:

*error: declaration of non-variable 'mxmlGetFirstChild(current)' in 'for' loop initial declaration*

I am compiling this code [cAER](https://github.com/llongi/caer) it's a big code, here is part of it:

```
for (mxml_node_t *current = mxmlGetFirstChild(node); current!=NULL; current = mxmlGetNextSibling){
```

...
}

I'll appreciate if someone give me a solution.
OS: Ubuntu 12.04 64bit
GCC: 4.9.2
std flag is set to c99 (I also tested c9x, gnu99 and c11)
libmxml1 2.6-2 is installed

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and its resolved. Still don't know why it was acting up on 12.04